# Using regex extract a particular text from a paragraph

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have used the below to extract a string from a paragraph.

```
data = '''actions/steps to (re-) produce the problem:
1) Media--> Music collectio--> on right side--> click on Add Favourite icon--> on clicking Add from Favourite icon--> (Delete from favourite ) will display--> again click on Delete the favourite

expected result/behaviour:
it should display the track as well

observed result/behavior:
1st track list will display then
2nd list of songs will display
3rd no records will display
this behaviour will appear again and again

possible impact: 
this can be an issue while driving

actions/steps to recover from error:
software version tested (including supplied software or CAF version if relevant):

MGU :- 17w.25.4-2'''

observed=[]

for i in data["Error Description"]:    
    if len(re.findall(r'(Observed result\/behavior:|observed result\/behavior:)([^(]*)Possible impact:', i))==1:    
        observed.append((re.findall(r'(Observed result\/behavior:|observed result\/behavior:)([^(]*)Possible impact:', i))[0][1])    
    else:    
        observed.append(" ".join((re.findall(r'(Observed result\/behavior:|observed result\/behavior:)([^(]*)Possible impact:', i))))
```

OUTPUT :

It shows nothing as the "observed:" has 4 lines. If it generally has one line and the immediate preceding is "possible impact:" then it displays the output.

I need my output though if the observed has n no of lines

Please help.

Comment: given the `data` you provided, would you please be clear on the desired output. i.e. what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Output should only contain the "observed :"  data.  for example in the above case the output should only be ""  observed result/behavior: 1st track list will display then 2nd list of songs will display 3rd no records will display this behaviour will appear again and again ""

Answer (score 0):

This should work on the assumption that `observed result/behavior:` will have one blank line before the next paragraph:

```
begin = data.index('observed result/behavior:')
end = data[begin:].index('\n\n')
output = data[begin:(begin+end)]

print(output)

observed result/behavior:
1st track list will display then
2nd list of songs will display
3rd no records will display
this behaviour will appear again and again
```

Comment: That looks great, but for some of the data I dont know whats the next preceding thing. In the above case, it ends with "possible impact", in some cases I dont know what it ends with. I have 7000 rows in my case. Could you assist me with that.

Comment: can you determine the number of lines under the `observed result/behavior:` ? I mean if you know the number of lines that follows it, you can extract the `n` lines.

Comment: updated the answer. It doesn't depend of `possible impact` now. But depends on line breaks

Comment: In all the cases i dont have blank cases. :( ..so in that case the above  code doesnt work